# How would C parse a = b---c?

Tags: c, parsing, operators, token, c-preprocessor

If C has to compile the following code

```
int a = 5, b = 3, c = 7;

a = b---c;
```

Would it have to parse it as `a = b-- - c`, `a = b - --c`, or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: It is *not* because of precedence. Only because length.

Comment: OK, Antti Haapala is right. K&R 2nd edition, A.21 Tokens says "If the input stream has been separated into tokens up to a given character, the next token is the longest string of characters that could constitute a token."

Answer (score 7):

The compiler considers the longest sequence of characters to determine a token.

So this statement

```
a = b---c;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = b-- - c;
```

That is in the expression of the right side of the assignment there is the postfix decrement operator `--` followed by the additive operator `-`.

From the C Standard (6.4 Lexical elements)

> 4 If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to
>   a given character, **the next preprocessing token is the longest
>   sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token**.
>   ...

Thus as result the values of the variables after executing this statement will be

```
a = -4, b = 2, c = 7
```

Also pay attention to that a valid sub-expression may be enclosed in parentheses.
You may write for example

```
a = ( b-- )-c;
```

but you may not write

```
a = ( b- )--c;
```

On the other hand, you may also write

```
a = b-( --c );
```

In this case the values of the variables after executing the statement will be

```
a = -3, b = 3, c = 6
```

Comment: Also known as [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).

Answer (score 1):

It is parsed as : **a = b-- - c**, and b-- means post-decrement, i.e. **decrement *after* taking the value of b to compute b - c**

run this code and watch the output :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 3, c = 7;

    a = b---c;

    printf ("a is : %d\n", a);
    printf ("b is : %d\n", b);
    printf ("c is : %d\n", c);
}
```

output :

```
a is : -4
b is : 2
c is : 7
```